# Does iCloud.com expose users detail/emails via API or some other method like library etc?

Tags: ios, asp.net, icloud, social-networking

I need to import contacts (email addresses) from iCloud.com.
I couldn't find any API or library on internet.
Does iCloud.com expose users detail/emails via API or some other method like library etc?

I'm talking about same functionality that Google/yahoo/Hotmail expose.

I'm working on social networking web site. I need to get contacts and send invitations.
I'm using asp.net4.0

Answer (score 3):

There is no public API for iCloud provided by Apple.